# I cannot figure out what wrong on MySQL keep getting error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

Executing SQL script in server

> ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VISIBLE,
>    CONSTRAINT `fk_WEEK_WORKOUT`
>      FOREIGN KEY (`WORKOUT_IdWorkout`)
>   ' at line 12

SQL Code:

```
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `mydb`.`WEEK`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`WEEK` (
      `WeekOne` VARCHAR(27) NOT NULL,
      `WeekTwo` VARCHAR(27) NOT NULL,
      `WeekThree` VARCHAR(27) NOT NULL,
      `WeekFour` VARCHAR(27) NOT NULL,
      `IdWeek` INT NOT NULL,
      `WORKOUT_IdWorkout` INT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`IdWeek`),
      INDEX `fk_WEEK_WORKOUT_idx` (`WORKOUT_IdWorkout` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_WEEK_WORKOUT`
        FOREIGN KEY (`WORKOUT_IdWorkout`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`WORKOUT` (`IdWorkout`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

I keep getting this every time no matter what what I change

Comment: Did you check the manual for your MySQL version to see if `VISIBLE` is supported in that version? It's not in all of them. Google *mysql documentation* to find the documentation for the specific version of MySQL you're using, and then read the documentation for `CREATE TABLE`. (Or more quickly, you could try searching this site for **mysql error 1064 visible** instead.)

Comment: Incidentally, consider if this is realy the optimal design for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL Invisible Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/invisible-indexes.html), that introduce the `VISIBLE` keyword, are available since version 8.0 onwards. You are probably running an earlier version.

The feature is called *invisible* indexes : this pinpoints that, in earlier versions of MySQL, indexes are always visible. Even in MySQL 8.0, indexes are visible by default, unless explicitly defined as `INVISIBLE`.

You can safely remove the `VISIBLE` keyword from your script, and it should work just fine (and consistently) on all versions of MySQL (assuming that table `WORKOUT` exists and that it has a unique column called `IdWorkout` of datatype `INT`).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6iQTwrMJ915mCUWgwDVRrM/0)**